# Null pointer exception in oracle-jdbc database change notification

Tags: java, multithreading, jdbc

```
DCNDemoListener: got an event (com.datasync.DCNDemoListener@587bf0 running on thread Thread[Thread-2,5,main])
Exception in thread "Thread-2" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.datasync.DCNDemoListener.onDatabaseChangeNotification(DBChangeNotification.java:142)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.NTFRegistration.notify(NTFRegistration.java:191)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.NTFConnection.unmarshalNSDataPacket(NTFConnection.java:578)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.NTFConnection.unmarshalOneNSPacket(NTFConnection.java:404)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.NTFConnection.run(NTFConnection.java:181)
```

Here is my code:

```
public void onDatabaseChangeNotification(DatabaseChangeEvent e)
      {
        Thread t = Thread.currentThread();
        System.out.println("DCNDemoListener: got an event ("+this+" running on thread "+t+")");
        System.out.println(e.getTableChangeDescription()[0].getRowChangeDescription()[0].getRowid().stringValue()); // line142
        System.out.println(e.toString());
        synchronized( demo )
        { demo.notify();}
      }
```

Tring to figure out but I have no clue what went wrong :(

Comment: Lines like this are a nightmare to debug. Break it up it multiple lines then you'll have a fighting chance of figuring it out: `e.getTableChangeDescription()[0].getRowChangeDescription()[0].getRowid().stringValue()`

Comment: Error is at line 142 which is 'System.out.println(e.getTableChangeDescription()[0].getRowChangeDescription()[0].getRowid().stringValue());' // line142

Comment: How do I break it up?

Comment: Assign each section to its own variable and inspect it

Answer (score 1):

Fixed it. I was actually trying to figure out the code I have written and while doing so I have copied a bit of code from a website which was pulling a record which is null in DB hence the error. Removing the code at line 142 fixed the isse